# Calculate element in matrix incrementally, using neighbors

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have this Java problem, which I suspect it relates to a higher-level algorithm, but my searches haven't been able to come up with anything practical.

You construct an array as follows:

```
1
1   1
1   2   1
1   3   3   1
1   4   6   4   1
1   5   10  10  5  1
```

Basically, A<sub>i,j</sub> = A<sub>i-1,j-1</sub>+A<sub>i-1,j</sub>. It's supposed to return the element at index (l, c): for (4, 1) it should return 4, (5, 2) returns 10, etc. My solution is straightforward, but it is not enough:

```
static long get(int l, int c){
    long[][] matrix = new long[l+1][l+1];
    matrix[0][0]=1;
    matrix[1][0]=1; 
    matrix[1][1]=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=l;i++){
        matrix[i][0]=1;
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1]+matrix[i-1][j];
        }   
    }
    return matrix[l][c];
}
```

It doesn't work for large values of l and c. Using BigInteger doesn't work. My searches have led me to loop skewing and scalarization, but I don't know where to start. Any steer in the right direction is really appreciated.

PS: Sorry for the newbie-vibe, this is my first question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are describing [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), for which a closed formula exists:

```
matrix[n][k] = n!/(k! * (n-k)!)
```

P.S. If these numbers seem familiar, it is because they are also from the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), where the common examples are:

```
(x+y)^2 = 1* x^2 + 2xy + 1*y^2
(x+y)^3 = 1*x^3 + 3*xy^2 + 3yx^2 + 1*y^3
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use a loop, this is simply [pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), the formula:

```
(n, k) = n! / ( k! * (n-k)!)
```

Will generate your answer for the position (n, k).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static long get(int l, int c) throws Exception {
    if (l != c)
         throw new Exception("l != c");
    long[][] matrix = new long[l+1][l+1];
    matrix[0][0]=1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= l; ++i) {
         for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
              if (j - 1 >= 0) {
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j] + matrix[i - 1][j - 1];
              } else {
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j];
              }
         }
    }
    return matrix[l][c];
}
```